# Spring Autowired - Not creating new Bean - Prototype

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired, executorservice

I am trying to autowire a bean which I marked scope as Prototype. Because I need to create new object under each iteration. But instead of creating new object , it keeps updating the same object with new values when I call the setter method inside the for loop. I am not sure what I am doing incorrectly . Please advise.

**Bean Configuration Class below**

```
@Configuration
public class DBConfigDev {

       @Bean
        @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
        public DuplexWorker prototypeDuplexBean(){
            return new DuplexWorker();
        }

}
```

**Bean Class Below**

```
public class DuplexWorker implements Callable {

    static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DuplexWorker.class);
    
        

    private List<PrintJobItem> printJobItems;
    
    private List<String> groupIds;
    
    
    private ArrayList duplexJobs;
    private String groupId;
    private CountDownLatch latch;

    
    public DuplexWorker() {
        
        
    }
    
    @Override
    public Object call() throws Exception {
            this.latch.countDown();
            
            
                return null;

        
}   
        
    /**
     * @return the duplexJobs
     */
    public ArrayList getDuplexJobs() {
        return duplexJobs;
    }



    /**
     * @param duplexJobs the duplexJobs to set
     */
    public void setDuplexJobs(ArrayList duplexJobs) {
        this.duplexJobs = duplexJobs;
    }



    /**
     * @return the groupId
     */
    public String getGroupId() {
        return groupId;
    }



    /**
     * @param groupId the groupId to set
     */
    public void setGroupId(String groupId) {
        logger.info("Going to Set GroupID :::"+this.groupId+":::"+Thread.currentThread().getName()+":::"+groupId);
        this.groupId = groupId;
    }



    /**
     * @return the latch
     */
    public CountDownLatch getLatch() {
        return latch;
    }



    /**
     * @param latch the latch to set
     */
    public void setLatch(CountDownLatch latch) {
        this.latch = latch;
    }

    
    
}
```

**Autowire Class where its not creating new objects below**
**I am expecting the call to setter method inside for loop will create new objects**

```
public class ProcessSimplex extends PrintBatchConstants implements Tasklet  {
    @Autowired
    private DuplexWorker prototypeDuplexBean;

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
        
        ArrayList<String> grpIds=(ArrayList)chunkContext.getStepContext().getJobExecutionContext().get(batchGroupIds);
        
/*                        grpIds.clear();
                          grpIds.add("86954");
*/      
    
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(grpIds.size());

        
        
        for (int i = 0; i < grpIds.size(); i++) {

            String[] args = new String[5];
            args[0]= PAPER_COLOR;
            args[1]= PAPER_SIZE;
            args[2]= DELIVERY_MODE;
            args[3]= PLEX;
            args[4]= grpIds.get(i);

            ArrayList simplexJobs = null;
            ArrayList duplexJobs = null;
            ArrayList allJobs = null;
            

            allJobs = CfBatchPrintUtil.getJobs(args);
            logger.info("AllJobs size "+allJobs.size());
            simplexJobs = CfBatchPrintUtil.getPrintJobsByType(allJobs, false);
            duplexJobs = CfBatchPrintUtil.getPrintJobsByType(allJobs, true);
                        
            logger.info("SimplexJobs size "+simplexJobs.size());
            logger.info("duplexJobs size "+duplexJobs.size());

            prototypeDuplexBean.setDuplexJobs(duplexJobs);
            prototypeDuplexBean.setLatch(latch);
            prototypeDuplexBean.setGroupId(args[4]);
            service.submit(prototypeDuplexBean);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

"Prototype" means that the Spring Bean Factory will create a new instance every time it is asked for a `DuplexWorker` bean.

`@Autowired` field `prototypeDuplexBean` is assigned whenever a new `ProcessSimplex` instance is created by Spring.

Since `ProcessSimplex` is probably a "singleton", it is only created once, and hence auto-wired field `prototypeDuplexBean` is only assigned once, and hence only one instance of `DuplexWorker` is ever created.

If another class also auto-wires `DuplexWorker`, it will get a different instance.

If `ProcessSimplex` is a "prototype" bean, then each instance of `ProcessSimplex` will be autowired with a difference instance of `DuplexWorker`. Since the question code doesn't show how `ProcessSimplex` is instantiated, it's unknown to us if this applies.

Comment: Even if the OP were getting a different bean on each _invocation_, he's reusing that same object inside a loop inside each invocation. Maybe worth recommending injecting a `Provider<DuplexBean>`.

Comment: Hi Andreas , Chrylis. Thanks for the suggestion. Now I understand on how the autowiring and bean creation works. ProcessSimplex is a managed bean by Spring. It is a tasklet executed as part of spring batch. Its a singleton. Is there no other way to create new beans for duplex worker ?

I tried instantiating ApplicationContext inside the execute method so that I can call getBean. But it tries to create all the beans again which was already created when Spring batch initialized and throws instance already available exception.